# Versioning in Excel web app

Tags: 2010, document-library, versioning, excel-services

Does anyone know how it's possible to create major and minor versions in the excel web app?
When a document is saved, I see that it changes the minor version, but what do I need to do to create a new major version? (Since there is no save button there...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know, if you want major AND minor versions, you will have to save ('Publish') a major version through the SharePoint UI. Excel Web App, Excel Services and even Excel itself on the user's machine will only 'save a version', without the ability to 'publish a major version'.